# Filter data by threshold, including first value surpassing threshold

Tags: r, dplyr

This seems like a simple problem, but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around it. I have a data frame of locations with population by region of birth, and I'm trying to filter for the regions whose combined population exceeds a threshold—in this case, 50%.

For example, for each location I need to be able to say something like, "In Fairfield County, a majority of the foreign-born population were born in Central and South America or the Caribbean." To be able to phrase it that way, I need to include the first country that gets over the 50% mark.

An abridged version of my data, along with the first few rows for each location, is here:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(name = c("Fairfield County", "Fairfield County", 
                              "Fairfield County", "Fairfield County", "Greater Hartford", "Greater Hartford", 
                              "Greater Hartford", "Greater Hartford", "Greater Hartford"), 
                     subregion = c("South America", "Central America", "Caribbean", 
                                   "South Central Asia", "Caribbean", "Eastern Europe", "South Central Asia", 
                                   "South America", "Southern Europe"), 
                     pop = c(40565, 33919, 32044, 17031, 26939, 23765, 20153, 14384, 9309), 
                     cum_share = c(0.2, 0.38, 0.54, 0.62, 0.2, 0.37, 0.51, 0.62, 0.69)), 
                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  top_n(4, pop)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name             subregion            pop cum_share
#>   <chr>            <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 Fairfield County South America      40565      0.2 
#> 2 Fairfield County Central America    33919      0.38
#> 3 Fairfield County Caribbean          32044      0.54
#> 4 Fairfield County South Central Asia 17031      0.62
#> 5 Greater Hartford Caribbean          26939      0.2 
#> 6 Greater Hartford Eastern Europe     23765      0.37
#> 7 Greater Hartford South Central Asia 20153      0.51
#> 8 Greater Hartford South America      14384      0.62
```

My first plan was to filter for where the cumulative share was less than or equal to 51%, meaning the top-ranking regions until reaching a majority of the population. The problem with that is that because these shares aren't a continuous distribution, having a set cutoff point like this doesn't work, because I need to include the first region for which the cumulative share is a majority.

```r
df %>%
  filter(cum_share <= 0.51)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   name             subregion            pop cum_share
#>   <chr>            <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 Fairfield County South America      40565      0.2 
#> 2 Fairfield County Central America    33919      0.38
#> 3 Greater Hartford Caribbean          26939      0.2 
#> 4 Greater Hartford Eastern Europe     23765      0.37
#> 5 Greater Hartford South Central Asia 20153      0.51
```

As you can see by comparing to the first snapshot, Greater Hartford works as I'd expect. But Fairfield County should include the Caribbean, at which the cumulative share is 54%; by filtering with a set threshold of 51%, Caribbean isn't included. What I'd like to get is instead like this:

```r
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   name             subregion            pop cum_share
#>   <chr>            <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 Fairfield County South America      40565      0.2 
#> 2 Fairfield County Central America    33919      0.38
#> 3 Fairfield County Caribbean          32044      0.54
#> 4 Greater Hartford Caribbean          26939      0.2 
#> 5 Greater Hartford Eastern Europe     23765      0.37
#> 6 Greater Hartford South Central Asia 20153      0.51
```

Here, the first place at which the share exceeds 50% is also included. I *could* filter manually, but I'm actually doing this by country, not region of the world, and for 18 locations, so it becomes unwieldy.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Wow, I'm realizing my own foolishness—I could have calculated cumulative shares from populations in *ascending* order, not *descending*, and then easily filtered for where this threshold exceeds 50%. I'll leave this up, though, to help out someone who doesn't have control over their data in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, for each location I need to be able to say something like, "In Fairfield County, a majority of the foreign-born population were born in Central and South America or the Caribbean."

For the general case of stopping after a condition is met, there's `filter(lag(cumsum(cond), default=FALSE) == 0)`

```
> df %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(cumsum(lag(cum_share > 0.5, default = FALSE)) == 0)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   name [2]
              name          subregion   pop cum_share
             <chr>              <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Fairfield County      South America 40565      0.20
2 Fairfield County    Central America 33919      0.38
3 Fairfield County          Caribbean 32044      0.54
4 Greater Hartford          Caribbean 26939      0.20
5 Greater Hartford     Eastern Europe 23765      0.37
6 Greater Hartford South Central Asia 20153      0.51
```

The OP identified a simpler filter in the case of a monotone condition (ie, one such that after first meeting the condition, later elements of the vector also do so): `filter(lag(cum_share, default = 0) <= 0.5)`.

There's probably a good way to wrap this in a function (mutate `.cond` from user input; mutate `.keep` criterion `= cumsum(lag(.cond, default=FALSE) == 0)`; filter; drop `.cond` and `.keep`), but I don't have the tidyverse NSE skills for the first step.

Comment: Thanks! I actually simplified the second solution you have here. It works to just filter by `lag(cum_share, default = 0)`, for where that's <= 0.5

Comment: @camille Oh, d'oh, nice improvement; I'll edit it in but will reverse if you want to self-answer.